# redux-websocket-autoreconnect Webpack compilation error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have a project in which I need to use **redux-websocket-autoreconnect**

When running webpack it gives me an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/redux-websocket-autoreconnect/src/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\workspaces\Engineering\projects\wcc\static\releaseBranches\25.X.X\src\clients\default\pmxd\node_modules\redux-websocket-autoreconnect\src\index.js Unexpected token (21:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const createMiddleware = () => {
|   // Hold a reference to the WebSocket instance in use.
|   let websocket: ?WebSocket;
|   let websocketConfig: ?Config
|
 @ ./app/store/configure.store.jsx 40:35-75
 @ ./app/app.jsx
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./app/app.jsx
```

In webpack.config.js I have this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'flow', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|WidgetLib|console)/
      },
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['flow', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test: /node_modules\/redux-websocket-autoreconnect/
      },....
```

My guess is that the error apparently is about the compiler not being able to recognize es2015 code in **index.js**, which is basically something like this:

```
const createMiddleware = () => {
  // Hold a reference to the WebSocket instance in use.
  let websocket: ?WebSocket;
  let websocketConfig: ?Config

  /**
   * A function to create the WebSocket object and attach the standard callbacks
   */
  const initialize = ({ dispatch }, config: Config) => {
    // Instantiate the websocket.
    websocket = createWebsocket(config);
    websocketConfig = config
```

The error occurs on Windows 10. (It compiles fine on Mac)

Using webpack@2.7.0, redux@3.7.2, react@15.6.2

Any idea of what could be missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove from webpack the rule with `test: /node_modules\/redux-websocket-autoreconnect/` the library is already transpiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to compile the package yourself by issuing

1. `yarn add matiere-noire/redux-websocket-autoreconnect`
2. `cd node_modules/redux-websocket-autoreconnect`
3. `yarn && yarn build`
4. edit `package.json` and point `main` to `dist` `"main": "dist/index.js"`

Second way is to build it with your webpack then 
according to the package maintainer `.babelrc` you'll need a couple of plugins.

```
  {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015'],
      plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread', 'transform-flow-strip-types']
    },
    test: /node_modules\/redux-websocket-autoreconnect/
  }
```

Comment: I removed the suggested piece of config code, but the error persists. Also the import statement is there in configure.store.. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: I just checked `package.json` of the `matiere-noire/redux-websocket-autoreconnect ` and he doesn't provide a transpiled version of the package. This is why you see the errors. It a good idea to pull it in with webpack and build it. I'll get back to you with a solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution! It seems odd that on Windows I have to do this manually, whilst on Mac it works transparently. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: You most definitely can build it like you tried by pulling it in from your webpack. Try the second way it might just work. Haven't tried it but it should work